# Negative order differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Are algebraic solutions for a function y(x) fulfilling this differential equation possible?

\begin{equation} 
 \text{y}^{-2}= \frac{\text{d}^2\text{y}}{\text{dx}^2}
\end{equation}

I found this differential equation, in the context of motion due to a fixed, repelling force that follows an inverse square law.

I figured out the following properties of y, when searching for numerical solutions, where i expect the algebraic solutions to show these features:

With given initial condition  $\text{y} > 0$:

\begin{equation} 
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\text{dy}}{\text{dx}} = \text{constant}
\end{equation}

I also know that the function is not going to "behave well" for $\lim_{y\to 0}$, due to its second derivative going to infinity in that case.

Comment: We do not say that this equation is of negative order, this is a second order differential equation since it involves second derivatives of y (and possibly lower too). (To my knowledge there is no special name that distinguishes cases where the exponent of y in your equation is 2 vs. when it is -2.)

Comment: Oh alright, thank you for the correction! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a hint**

The differential equation can be written as

$$\frac {y'}{y^2}=y' y''$$

and after integration

$$\frac {-1}{y}=\frac {1}{2}(y')^2+C$$